# Index was outside the bounds of the array - VB2008

Tags: vb.net

Why am i keep on getting this error: Index was outside the bounds of the array. Please help. Thank you.

```
 Dim list As New ListBox
 Dim dirsize As Integer
 Dim a As Integer
 Dim container(0) As String

 Dim counter As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of String)
 counter = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("C:\myfolder")
 dirsize = counter.Count

 For a = 0 To dirsize

     container(a) = a + 1
     lstItems.Items.Add(container(a))

 Next
```

Comment: For a = 0 To dirsize - 1

Comment: keeps on getting the same error

Comment: The error is on container(a) = a + 1 or in the for?

Comment: in container(a) = a + 1

Comment: I don't know what it container for. You need to ReDim to the size of dirsize or use anything else. Basically Dim container(0) as string is just that. An array with 1 position.

Comment: i'm using container to hold names of files inside the directory then store it as an array...then i will loop inside the folder to compare names of files.

Answer (score 1):

Basically `container` has only 1 element which you dim at the beginning of your sub. You never resize container, so if `dirsize` is anything else than 0 you will get this error.

You should do something like:

```
 Dim list As New ListBox
 Dim dirsize As Integer
 Dim a As Integer
 Dim container() As String

 Dim counter As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of String)
 counter = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("C:\myfolder")
 dirsize = counter.Count

 **ReDIm container(dirsize)**
 For a = 0 To dirsize

     container(a) = a + 1
     lstItems.Items.Add(container(a))

 Next
```